# Access Android Device Filter from Build Settings via code

Tags: c#, android, plugins, unity-game-engine

I am writing an extension for the Unity Editor.. 
I need to programmatically access and check the current Device Filter that have been selected from the "other settings" tab that appears in "player settings" option when you select build. 
I need to selectively add a few files in the project based on this check. I have no direction as of now. Would appreciate any sort of help. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, it is not named `PlayerSettings.deviceFilter` like one would expect since that's what it is displayed as in the Editor. It is called `targetDevice` and can be accessed from [`PlayerSettings.Android.targetDevice`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2017.3/Documentation/ScriptReference/PlayerSettings.Android-targetDevice.html).

Example of accessing it:

```
AndroidTargetDevice targetDevice = PlayerSettings.Android.targetDevice;
```

Can also be changed:

```
PlayerSettings.Android.targetDevice = AndroidTargetDevice.ARMv7;
PlayerSettings.Android.targetDevice = AndroidTargetDevice.FAT;
PlayerSettings.Android.targetDevice = AndroidTargetDevice.x86;
```